# Margins with Divs

Tags: html, css

I'm following a tutorial on how and when to use div's. The tutorial can be found here:

http://www.webreference.com/authoring/style/sheets/layout/advanced/index.html

I made four div's with the classes, level0, level1, level2, and level3 respectively. Like this:

```
<div id="level0"></div>
<div id="level1"></div>
<div id="level2"></div>
<div id="level3"></div>
```

So I'm working on div #1. The first CSS code implemented is basically setting up margins on the left and right. I think some of my previous CSS might be conflicting but I'm not sure where.

The CSS code for the body is:

```
body
{
background-color:#FBF8EF;
margin:9px 9px 0 9px;
padding 0;
}
```

Next the CSS code for div #1 (or rather div #0) is:

```
#level0
{
background-color:#FC0;
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm following the tutorial incorrectly or if I'm just writing it wrong but if anyone could lend assistance it would help. Let me know if I missed anything.

Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: please added in fiddle

Comment: can you create fiddle for this?

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full implementation for the tutorial you mentioned. you forgot the nesting of divs and also css for others divs.

here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/WRnUv/

```
body
{
background-color:#FBF8EF;
margin:9px 9px 0 9px;
padding 0;
}
#level0
{
background-color:#FC0;
}
#level1 {
    margin-left:143px;
    padding-left:9px;
    background:#FFF;
}
#level2 {
    background:#FFF3AC;
}
#level3 {
    margin-right:143px;
    padding-right:9px;
    background:#FFF;
}

<div id="level0">
  <div id="level1"> Level 1
    <div id="level2"> Level 2
      <div id="level3"> Level 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't seem to follow the tutorial and nest your divs:

```
<div id="level0">
  <div id="level1"> Level 1
    <div id="level2"> Level 2
      <div id="level3"> Level 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A div with no content and no width or height set will not take up space on the screen and therefor will not show the color. Give it some content or dimensions.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HaJc4/

```
<div id="level0">content</div>
<div id="level1"></div>
<div id="level2"></div>
<div id="level3"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't really fix his issue, which was he didn't follow the tutorial correctly and nest his divs

Comment: Quite right. I jumped right in without looking at the link. It's late and I am sleepy. (Not a real excuse, I know.) - but it is good info for him to file away for a later date.